# Conditional threading through expressions

Tags: clojure

I was trying to do something like below,

```
val = initValue;
if (test1(val)) { val = fn1(val); }
if (test2(val)) { val = fn2(val); }
return val;
```

The only way I found within clojure core was using `cond->`. I was hoping I should be able to do this

```
(cond-> initValue
   test1 fn1
   test2 fn2)
```

However, the condition in `cond->` is not a function. It doesn't seem to allow me to pass the result of `fn1` to `test2`.

What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Well you have a data dependency between the function results and your predicates, so the "nicest" thing I came up using only clojure.core is to compose `as->` and `cond->`

```
(as-> initValue data
      (cond-> data (test1 data) (f1 data))
      (cond-> data (test2 data) (f2 data)))
```

Another approach would be my own [`update-when`](https://github.com/arrdem/detritus/blob/master/src/detritus/update.clj#L73) helper...

```
(defn ->when-update
  "Function of a value, a predicate, an updater and optional
  varargs. If the predicate is true of the value, returns (apply f x
  args), otherwise returns x.

  Example:
    (-> 1 (->when-update #(<= 0 %) inc))"
  [x pred f & args]
  (if (pred x)
    (apply f x args)
    x))
```

which lets us write

```
(-> initValue
    (->when-update test1 f1)
    (->when-update test2 f2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
(defmacro cond-chain [init & stuff]
  (let [pairs (partition 2 stuff)
        step-form (fn [[test func]]
                    `((fn [x#] (if (~test x#) (~func x#) x#))))]
    (list* '->> init (map step-form pairs))))
```

For example,

```
(cond-chain 7, even? inc, odd? #(* 2 %))
;14

(cond-chain 7, odd? inc, odd? #(* 2 %))
;8

(cond-chain 7, zero? inc, even? #(* 2 %))
;7
```

As you can see, it constructs a form that conditionally applies each of a series of functions.

---

Or, without resorting to macros:

```
(defn cond-chain [init & stuff]
  (let [pairs (partition 2 stuff)]
    (reduce (fn [acc [test func]] (if (test acc) (func acc) acc)) init pairs)))
```